# Print data from a json using dynamic routing in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-router

I'm creating a clone version of netflix with reactjs but I'm stuck and don't know what else to do. I've tried watching some yt videos and reading some articles online but no luck.

I'm trying to show the selected media on a separate page (using react-router) but I don't know why is not showing. The information that I need to show comes from a json file that I created (the json file is one huge object with two arrays (one for series and the other one with movies)

This is the code for the selected media page:

```
import React from "react"
import Navbar from "../Components/Navbar"
import Selected from "../Components/Content/Hero"
import Body from "../Components/Content/Body"
import Footer from "../Components/Footer"
import "../../src/Pages/style.scss"
import courflix from "../data/courflix.json"

class MediaPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      up: "iconStyle",
      down: "iconStyle",
      name: "",
      rating: "",
      synopsis: "",
      year: "",
      seasons: "",
      cover: ""
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const datium = courflix
     const courflixArrayTwo = Object.values(datium)

    const filtered = courflixArrayTwo.filter((flix) => {
      return flix.id === this.props.match.params.id
      console.log(this.props.match) ;
    })

    this.setState({
      name:filtered.name,
      rating:filtered.rating,
      synopsis:filtered.synopsis,
      year:filtered.year,
      seasons:filtered.seasons,
      cover:filtered.cover
    })
    console.log(filtered)
  }

  render() {
     const { name, rating, synopsis, year, seasons, cover } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="app-wrapper">
        <Navbar />
        <Selected
          name={name}
          rating={rating}
          synopsis={synopsis}
          year={year}
          seasons={seasons}
          cover={cover}
        />
        <Body/>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MediaPage
```

this is the code for the component where I want the data to be displayed

```
import React from "react";
import { faThumbsUp } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import courflix from "../data/courflix.json"
import "./style.scss";

class Selected extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      up: "iconStyle",
      down: "iconStyle",
    };
  }

  handleClickUp() {
    if (this.state.up === "iconStyle") {
      this.setState({
        up: "iconStyle up",
        down: "iconStyle",
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        up: "iconStyle",
      });
    }
  }

  handelClickDown() {
    if (this.state.down === "iconStyle") {
      this.setState({
        down: "iconStyle down",
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        down: "iconStyle",
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {name, rating, synopsis, year, seasons,cover} = this.props;
    const {up,down} =this.state;
    
    return (
      <div className="hero-wrapper">
        <div className="general-wrapper">
          <p className="name"> {name}</p>
          <div className="content-details">
            <p className="year">{year}</p>
            <p className="rating">{rating}</p>
            <p className="seasons"> {seasons}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="hero-synopsis">
            <p className="synopsis">{synopsis}</p>
          </div>
          <a href="http://google.com" className="button">
            Play Media
          </a>
          <a href="http://google.com" className="button">
            Add to "My list"
          </a>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faThumbsUp}
            className={up}
            onClick={() => this.handleClickUp()}
          />
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faThumbsUp}
            rotation={180}
            className={down}
            onClick={() => this.handelClickDown()}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Selected
```

The code for the json object is here: https://codeshare.io/AdreOk

and the routing here:

https://codeshare.io/ZJRPWQ

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import MediaPage from './Pages/Media';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
    <Route exact path="/content/:id" component={MediaPage}/>
    <Route exact path="/mylist/" component={MediaPage} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include all the relevant code you are working with as part of a complete [mcve], including the routing code/logic?

Comment: Ok, and what/where are you trying to work with any JSON object? Is it this import `import courflix from "../data/courflix.json"`?

Comment: I think I see now. Is the issue that the filtering works only once when the component mounts?

Comment: the issue is that I don't see the data from the selected media in the page. I should see it when the component mounts but I don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

1. The `courflix.json` file is an object with two root keys that are arrays, `"series"` and `"movies"`. The `MediaPage` is creating an array of the values, i.e. an array of two arrays, instead of a single flattened list of "flix" objects.
2. The next chunk of logic attempts to filter this array of arrays and compare each to the current `id` route path parameter. Arrays don't have an `id` property, so `flix.id` is undefined and the result is an empty array.
3. `filtered` is an array, not an object. `Array.prototype.filter` returns an array. Attempting to access properties `name`, `rating`, etc from an array are also undefined values.

Code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const datium = courflix;
  const courflixArrayTwo = Object.values(datium);      // (1)

  const filtered = courflixArrayTwo.filter((flix) => { // (3)
    return flix.id === this.props.match.params.id;     // (2)
  });

  this.setState({
    name: filtered.name,
    rating: filtered.rating,
    synopsis: filtered.synopsis,
    year: filtered.year,
    seasons: filtered.seasons,
    cover: filtered.cover
  });
  console.log(filtered);
}
```

## Solution

1. Access both the `"series"` and `"movies"` arrays and flatten down to a single array.
2. Use `Array.prototype.find` instead of `Array.prototype.filter` to search the array and return the first matching element.
3. Check the `.find` returned a defined object and access the `name`, `rating`, etc properties.

Code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const filtered = [...courflix.series, ...courflix.movies] // (1)
    .find((flix) => {                                       // (2)
      return flix.id === this.props.match.params.id;
    });

  if (filtered) {                                           // (3)
    this.setState({
      name: filtered.name,
      rating: filtered.rating,
      synopsis: filtered.synopsis,
      year: filtered.year,
      seasons: filtered.seasons,
      cover: filtered.cover
    });
  }
}
```

[image: Edit print-data-from-a-json-using-dynamic-routing-in-react-js]

[image]